# Windows Mobile - detecting when power off button is pressed

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there an easy way to get notified when user presses Power Off button on it's Windows Mobile device? Using C# of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331343/detect-and-prevent-delay-windows-mobile-power-off

Comment: I wouldn't call this a dupe.  he wants to get notified, but not prevent it.

Comment: I must vent out my frustration here - state of Windows Mobile SDK right now is - pathetic. I start background activity and there is no way to turn it off - it continues to run even though user pressed PowerOff button. On the other hand code that's supposed to act and stop that background activity for user's convince CAN'T be executed. Awesome, just freaking awesome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the power button is pressed, the power manager will send out a notification of a state change.  You can request that the PM send you a notification by calling [RequestPowerNotifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919833.aspx) You have to send in a handle to a [point-to-point messgae queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885180.aspx) (managed version [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446556.aspx)) that will get the notification.

For thos who don't want to write all of the glue to make this work, all of this is already pre-done for you in the SDF's [PowerManagement class](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/4c0b462f-7bec-163a-c42c-59788860c4c7.htm).

Also be forewarned that just becasue you request the notification does *not* mean that your app will get the notification before the state change occurs.  For example on pwer down it's pretty common that an app won't see the notification, and almost certain that even if you do see it you won't have time to execute anything before suspend actually occurs.  Typically your handler will run when the device resumes (followed by any handler for the resume state).

The power manager doesn't wait for you, it simply broadcasts a message.  You cannot use this to run code before a shutdown.

Comment: Hmph... I have sound playing that continues to run even if power button is pressed... so I'll try to just set switch to autoplay=false;

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting "Could not load type 'OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.PowerManagement' from assembly 'OpenNETCF.WindowsCE" when I try to use PowerManagement class?

Comment: Sounds like you have an assembly version mismatch or something - maybe multiple copies of different versions of SDF binaries or something.

Comment: Yeah... it was my genius idea to copy DLL into solution folder, not knowing that it requres three more DLLs: opennetcf.dll, opennetcf.configuration.dll and opennetcf.windowsce.messaging.dll ... it's definitely time to get some sleep. Thanks for your help...

Comment: And you were right, this event is pretty much useless... sometimes I manage to set flag to false, sometimes not... damn race condition

Answer (score 1):

I just  place CreateMsgQueue() into the XIP RPM binaries, without need for source code or OEM help.  you need to use a hex editor and a few tools from XDA forums.

```
<DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function CreateMsgQueue(ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal lpOptions As MsgQueueOptions) As IntPtr
End Function
```

also you should just create a simple driver for blocking the power down event, your driver is allowed to hold up the power down process in the PowerDown device Event. that way you get a guaranteed event that you can set the flag and stop your background running process, and store any variables, and then restore them on ther PowerUp event, which is also a standard evc++ event for winCE device driver. Pretty simple really. there is 100s of demo source code on the internet for this, I've seen it on 100s of sites.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, on the Windows CE 6 device i am using, CreateMsgQueue does not exist in CoreDll. Any other suggestions?

The only thing i can think of is continually checking Environment.TickCount against the device's real time clock. If time has moved forward but not the tick count, then presumably the device was sleeping.

Dont like this solution because it will get tricked if the time jumps due to a failure in the device's real time clock

Comment: Can you change the image?  CreateMsgQueue is a really, really common API and I'm surprised your OS doesn't have it.  I'm not saying it doesn't, but images stripped down that far really have limited capabilities.  I'd try hard to either create a new OS with queue support or talk with the OEM about adding it.

Comment: I actually gave up on this... it's clear demonstration of how broken WM is ;(